# What can be done to troubleshoot or diagnose intermittent VPN connects, and disconnects?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, vpn

Internal VPN Fails to Connect - Sometimes, but not always.

```
racoon[337] IPSec connecting to server aaa.bbb.cc.dd
racoon[337] Connecting.
racoon[337] IPSec Phase1 started (Initiated by me).
racoon[337] IKE Packet: transmit success. (Initiator, Aggressive-Mode message 1).
racoon[337] IKE Packet: transmit success. (Phase1 Retransmit).
racoon[337] IKE Packet: transmit success. (Phase1 Retransmit).
racoon[337] IKE Packet: transmit success. (Phase1 Retransmit).
racoon[337] IPSec disconnecting from server aaa.bbb.cc.dd
racoon[337] IPSec disconnecting from server aaa.bbb.cc.dd
```

All magic codes are in place.  Pinging server is successful.  It's as if something sits waiting for a timer before allowing me to log in again.

I have a MacBook Pro running 10.8.4.

What am I missing?  Any suggestions for configuration/provisioning checks or changes?

Mike, thanks for cleaning this up.

Granted the VPN does disconnect throughout the day, sometimes often.  The big issue is the first attempt to connect in the morning.  Nearly 100% of the time it requires several (3 - 8) failed attempts, followed by an inactive period of 5 to 10 minutes, before it will connect for the first time of the day.